# How to undo 'git commit'

Tags: git

I would like to undo the last Git action, `git commit`.

I would like to see it completely gone from history.
I would also like to have all the included changes as local changes in my working copy, so later they can be committed.

Nothing is pushed yet.

What I **dont** want:

- `git revert` - that will just create an other commit that contains the negative of my erroneous commit which I should not have made in the first place
- `git reset --hard` OR `--soft` - that will not convert the changes from the commit back to local changes, only leave there what I still have uncommitted (with --soft)

Comment: Can you give an example for how `git reset --soft` will not work for you? I find it difficult to understand the difference between what it does and what you want.

Comment: I did `git reset --soft`, but now `git status` shows my working directory is clean, nothing to be committed. I want everything that was committed to be there in the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `git reset --soft` will remove the commit from your history, but keeps the changes in your working copy.

Comment: According to the docs it doesn't? Am I misunderstanding it? It would leave any local changes I still have uncommitted untouched, but it will not revert the committed changes back to local changes.

Comment: @PeterV: `git reset --soft` won't affect the working copy at all. It will just reset the `HEAD` pointer to the second most recent commit, effectively removing the most recent from the history.

Comment: Doesn't this require a `HEAD^` argument?

Comment: @echristopherson: Yes (or whichever commit you want to reset to).